# Import excel extract to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import an excel file that is generated from another system. The format of the excel file is not the prettiest, and I am trying to account for that in the VBA so that the user does not have to do manual file manipulation. The excel file is structured like so:

- Row 1-5: administrative data, one merged cell
- Row 6: Column headers. Valid space is columns A through R. There are additional columns, but I only need A-R.
- Row 7-n: Data. It is a weekly generated excel file, so the length varies.
- Row n+1: New admin header followed by additional data. I don't need this part or I might need to import it in a separate step later (haven't determined yet).

I was using this guide as a roadmap: https://mydatacareer.com/how-to-import-excel-into-access/ since it seemed to allow me to start the row and specify which columns. My current test is just going columns A-K. The script runs and it says done, but the data is not populated in the sheet.

```
Private Sub cmdImportExcel_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmdImportExcel_Click_err:
    
    Dim fdObj As Office.FileDialog 'declares variable fdObj
    Dim varfile As Variant 'variant type variable that will store the selected file path
    
    Set fdObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'instantiates the variable creating a filepicker object using early binding
    With fdObj 'using the with statement we will be working with fdObj by default
        'does not allow selecting more than one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'clears the file dialog file type existing filters
        .Filters.Clear
        'this file dialog will only allow the selection of excel files, this is achieved by handling the Filters collection
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007", "*.xlsx"
        'optional set the file dialog title
        .Title = "Please select the excel file to import …"
        .Show
    
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then 'a file was selected so data can be imported from Excel from this point the loop import process will run
            'variables declaration
            
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 'the excel application
            Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook 'the excel workbook reference that will point to the opened workbook
            Dim xlWs As Excel.Worksheet 'the excel worksheet with data
            Dim intLine As Long 'the line counter
            Dim strSqlDml As String 'string variable that stores the executed SQL statements
            Dim strColumnAcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnBcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnCcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnDcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnEcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnFcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnGcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnHcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnIcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnJcleaned As String
            Dim strColumnKcleaned As String
            
            varfile = .SelectedItems(1) 'picking the selected file full path
            
            'clean the existing table
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Sheet", dbFailOnError
            
            'instantiate the Excel application, creating the Excel application in memory, the excel Accplication will be visible so the user is able to see the loop iterating through Excel rows but usually it is hidden and only visible if indeed required
            
            Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlApp.Visible = False
            'Opening the picked file by calling the Excel workbooks collection open method, it receives the file location as a parameter and returns a reference for the opened file
            Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(varfile)
            'setting the worksheet to the first one within the available, as it is the one having data to be imported
            Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
            'default counter initial value/line, this means we start iterating in line one
            intLine = 6
            
            Do
            'the next lines replace single quotes in column B value and commas by dots as decimal separators in column G
            strColumnAcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 1).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnBcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 2).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnCcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 3).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnDcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 4).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnEcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 5).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnFcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 6).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnGcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 7).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnHcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 8).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnIcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 9).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnJcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 10).Value2, "", """")
            strColumnKcleaned = Replace(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 11).Value2, "", """")
           
            'the next line creates a SQL insert statement using the previously obtained cleaned variables
            strSqlDml = "INSERT INTO Sheet VALUES('" & strColumnAcleaned & "','" & strColumnBcleaned & "', '" & strColumnCcleaned & "','" & strColumnDcleaned & "','" & strColumnEcleaned & "','" & strColumnFcleaned & "', " & strColumnGcleaned & "'" & strColumnHcleaned & "''" & strColumnIcleaned & "','" & strColumnJcleaned & "','" & strColumnKcleaned & "')"
        
            'executes the insert statement against the database, the dbFailOnError is an optional value that will make the Execute process return an error if the SQL was not properly executed
            CurrentDb.Execute strSqlDml, dbFailOnError
            
            intLine = intLine + 1
            
            Loop Until IsEmpty(xlWs.Cells(intLine, 1)) 'stopping criteria, when values in column A stop the loop will stop, please note in cells collection the first index is the row and the second one the column so we are making row changing. Once the loop stops the steps after close the open workbook, quit excel and clean the memory references to the created objects
            xlWb.Close False
            xlApp.Quit
            
            Set xlApp = Nothing
            Set xlWb = Nothing
            Set xlWs = Nothing
    
            'the next step opens the loaded table so the user can see imported data
            DoCmd.OpenTable "Sheet", acViewNormal, acEdit
            'This branch only happens if no file was selected
        Else 'no file was selected
            Call MsgBox("No file was selected.")
        End If
    End With
Exit Sub

cmdImportExcel_Click_err:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 3075
        Call MsgBox("Done")
    Case Else
        Call MsgBox(Err.Number & " – " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "System Error …")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked for _Named Ranges_ in the workbook? If found, one might be for the data range. If not fourn, you could open the file via automation, create a Named Range holding the data, and save the file. Then, in Access, it is simple to _link_ the Named Range as a table. When done, use this linked table as source in a simple select query, where you can filter and convert data before appending these to your final table(s).

Comment: This looks pretty messy. Maybe you should save the Excel file as a CSV file, import that into Access, and go from there. Start with the simple, and go to the complex. Excel has ALL KINDS of stuff that a CSV file won't have. Any one of a number of things can prevent your import process from working.